# Command to dump IP route

Tags: linux, networking, routes, ip

Is there any way to dump IP route so that I can save this dump in database and then execute the routing commands one by one without having any error. (I am not network guy but working on an application which interacts with the network)

Please note that currently I am using 'ip route list' but getting errors as these commands are not in proper order. Some of the gateways must be reachable first before routing other IP address from these gateways.

Answer (score 0):

with a router, you can use the `show ip route static` to display the static route, for dynamic route, it has no meaning dump because they are all generate by the router.

Comment: Different company have similar commands, such as Huawei, use display route protocol static, Juniper user show route protocol static, and so on.